# Detect if SSL is supported

Tags: .net, ssl

I am redirecting users to https using a HttpModule for selected pages, what I don't want is to force users to use SSL if for some reason there browser, proxy, etc does not support it.  Is it possible to detect if the client supports SSL connections using .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try to perform the SSL connection using a WebClient, but is that going to prove that the browser supports it as well?

UPDATE: Oh you want **server-side** .NET to test for it. Can't do that.

Besides, why would the browser or proxy not support it? HTTPS is very common these days (as it has been for the last decade).

Comment: "why would the browser or proxy not support it?" That is what I said when asked what would happen if they don't support SSL.

Comment: If IIS is used, then for such clients, 403 status code will be returned. You have the choice to change the error page to your own. 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/groups/net-asp/347085-detect-https

Hopefully this helps. Be sure to read down.

edit:... ignore. re-read Q and this is answering something a little different

Answer (score 0):

Using serverside .NET - no.
You can try to make invisible call to HTTPS page via Javascript on first page load.